# Typescript add custom type definitions for esm library from commonjs project

Tags: typescript, es6-modules, esmodules, typescript-module-resolution, keycloak-admin-client

When using commonjs libraries it is possible to extend/overwrite their type, for example:

```
declare module 'ramda' {
  function path<T>(path: Path, obj: any): T;
}
```

But how can we do this with esm libraries?
I am trying to achieve same thing with *@keycloak/keycloak-admin-client*:

```
declare module '@keycloak/keycloak-admin-client' {
  function getNum(): number;
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
The current file is a CommonJS module whose imports will produce 'require' calls;
however, the referenced file is an ECMAScript module and cannot be imported with 'require'.
Consider writing a dynamic 'import("@keycloak/keycloak-admin-client")' call instead.
To convert this file to an ECMAScript module, change its file extension to '.mts',
or add the field `"type": "module"` to '/workspaces/project-name/backend/package.json'.
```

I am not ready to migrate my entire project to esm yet. So how can I declare types for esm external libraries?